# My number ends in the wrong decimal

Tags: python, floating-point

```
radius = float(input())
print('Enter the radius:', radius)
pi = 3.1415
volume = (4 / 3) * pi * radius * radius * radius
print('The volume is ', volume)
```

From this the expected value is

Enter the radius: 10.0
The volume is 4188.666666666667

However, I get the volume as 4188.666666666666

How do I fix this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Comment: This question crops up frequently, read this post [floating point math broken](http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/4777872)

Comment: What, precisely, are your requirements?

Comment: Note that your value of *pi* also has a rather limited precision (even worse than float).